# what is meaning of this error below and how to connect Django to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, django, database-connection

I have a django project that must use Sql Server database in order to stored and retrieve data.

I changed the engine in the **settings.py** and perform the migration.

the database  was successfully migrate into the sql server.

The problem is when I tried to create a model in django  and try to insert data to the model it seams that as there is no connection between the **model and the sql server**.

I tried to open django shell  and try to connect to sql server
using this command :

```
import pyodbc
connection  = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};' 'Server=localhost;' 'Database=testDB;')
```

it display the below error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server [2].  (2) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0);
>   [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or
>   instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection
>   to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if
>   instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
>   (2)')

and if i write the syntax below:

```
connection  = pyodbc.connect('Driver=(ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server);' 'Server=localhost;' 'Database=testDB;')
```

it display the below error:

> pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
>   (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Answer (score 0):

to fix this error it was a very simple adding to the server name where you must specified the servername **\SQLEXPRESS** in order to make the path for the server right.